# Xcode Orientation UIView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiview, orientation

I would like to use a different UIView for Landscape than for Portrait mode, is that possible and if so how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a global variable say "currentOrientationView" in .h file.
When ever your device is going to rotate from any interface orientation it will call "WillRotateToInterfaceOrientation:",this method has a parameter that tells the interface orientation to which the device is going to rotate so put your condition in this method and set the value of "currentOrientationView" with corresponding view as:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
    currentOrientationView=potraitView;
}else {
    currentOrientationView=landscapeView;;
}}
```

Comment: in your .h file of the view controller take one variable of type "UIView" as UIView *currentOrientationView;

Answer (score 1):

you must use the method shouldAutorotatetointerface orientation,
and inside this method you have to put code like

[self.addSubview:newView];

Comment: Sorry but altering views should not be done in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: but without the '.' between self and addSubview?

Answer (score 1):

Use willRotateToInterfaceOrientation to exchange views. shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation should return YES for all orientations you'd like to support.